# What does the 'Classic' Player Style do?

Tags: castlevania-the-adventure-rebirth

After beating *Castlevania: The Adventure ReBirth* for the first time, I unlocked a setting called "Player Style" in the options menu. I can select either *Normal* or *Classic* style.

I presume that Classic style is a reference to the original *Castlevania: The Adventure* on Game Boy, but I don’t have enough experience with the original to know what’s changed.

**What does the Classic Player Style option do? How does it differ from Normal?**

Comment: Not to be too blunt, but you ARE aware that Castlevania: The Adventure ReBirth is a remake of another game, yes?

Comment: @Powerlord I was aware it was a remake, but I have little to no experience with the Game Boy original.

Comment: The original Game Boy release are very, VERY old.  They're legally adults now.  You can't expect people to find this information easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Classic Style changes the character control to mimic the original game:

> 1. The direction of your jump cannot change mid-air.
> 2. Only Holy Water and Cross sub-weapons.
> 3. No whipping in the other direction in mid-air.
> 4. The Flame power-up will end as soon as you are hit.

[Source](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/wii/973241-castlevania-the-adventure-rebirth/answers/145739-what-does-the-classic-style-do)